# How to send the contents of a newly created row in an SQL Azure Database to a Service Bus Queue using Logic Apps?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps, azureservicebus

I am trying to implement a very basic functionality, as follows: when a row is added in an Azure SQL Database the contents of that row are sent to a Service Bus Queue.

[image: How to add row contents to 'Send Message' content]

(1)How do I send the 'row' as parameter to the 'send message content'? (2)What kind of object does 'get row' create, and what kind of formatting does it need to be sent over to the Service Bus Queue? (3)Can't this whole operation be done with an Azure Function, rather than logic apps ? (I couldn't find an SQL trigger for Azure Functions).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. We have created logic app as shown below:

[image]

2. Created a compose action to get newly added row content as shown below:
   [image]
3. Assigned value of compose to a variable as shown below:

[image]

4. In send message action, giving value of variable in content.
   [image]
5. Logic app ran successfully.
   [image]
6. Message received in service bus queue.
   [image]
7. You can get primary column by writing expression as **“triggerBody()?[primarycolumnname]”**
   [image]

Comment: Thank you! I do however encounter 2 more issues: At the 'get row' action, the only accepted formatting for the 'row id' input is: triggerBody()?['Id'] . What I'm saying is that unless I put Id in single quotes, it throws an 'Invalid Expression' error. Should it work without the quotes? Also, after adding the input for the field, it remains in a purple function rectangle, rather than interpreted as an SQL object as in your last photo. Also, at the 'Send Message' action, 'Row' is not interpreted as an object (just remains plain text, rather than shown in a purple rectangle as in your photo).

Comment: 1. As per documentation, we have to give filed name in single quotes. Please find below link for your reference [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference)
2. You can select id by using dynamic content.  Then ID will be interpreted as an SQL object. You can check the below image for your reference.
[link](https://i.imgur.com/1qCVujT.png)
For the second question,
You can give value for content as variables(‘variablename’) in Expression. Please find the image for your reference 
[link](https://i.imgur.com/vw2MVAS.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is no SQL trigger for azure functions. But, if you want to use azure functions for doing the same operation, you could use a `HttpTrigger` in logic app.

Just pass in the Unique Identifier of the inserted row as query parameter or in the request body. Then, read the data from DB and do the processing in azure functions.

If you are going the service bus route, you can `pass data in JSON format` and de-serialize this JSON at the retrieving end.

Comment: Okay, so it can be done with Azure Functions, with a slightly different approach (therefore issue no.3 is clarified). 

The main question remains unanswered - how do you add the 'row' obtained in the Get Row action to the contents of the Send Message action? Is it even correct to get the Id of the inserted row using @@identity?

Thank you!

Comment: If you clear the field, you should see an option `Add dynamic content` just below the row id.  Select the `primary key` column for Row Id. Now pass in the same key (or any other additional info too) to the service bus and do the rest of the processing.

Comment: As for the content format, I believe you can format it there like `{ Id: {value}, OtherProperty: {value} }`. Getting the value for the fields, need to check if column can be accessed with `Add dynamic content` or you need to use something along the line of  `row().outputs.Id`. Not really sure.

Comment: Thanks you once again, but I still cannot make it work. I encounter the following: (1)After selecting "add dynamic content" for the "row id" field I see no "primary key" option to select, from the dialog box. Also, I do not understand the following: the primary key is simply an 'id' column in my table. How would the 'get row' action know what row it should return, if I pass in a column name?  (2) Is it possible that the connection to the database is faulty? How could I check that?